# Divergent bounded sequence such that limit of the difference between two consecutive elements is zero

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, divergent-series

I'm asked to give an example of a sequence $a_n$ which is bounded, have no limit and upholds this rule: $\lim_{n\to \infty}|a_{n+1}-a_n|=0$. I tried a lot of sequences but it didn't work.

Comment: series or sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the $k$th triangular number, let's say $T_0=0$ and $T_k=\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$ for any integer $k>0$. Now define the sequence $b_n$ as follows:
$$b_n=(-1)^{k+1}\frac{1}{k}\qquad\text{iff }\;\;T_{k-1}<n\le T_k$$
The first terms of this sequence are:
$$1,\;-\frac12,\;-\frac12,\;\frac13,\;\frac13,\;\frac13,\;-\frac14,\;-\frac14,\;-\frac14,\;-\frac14,\;\frac15,\;\frac15,\;\frac15,\;\frac15,\;\frac15,\ldots$$
And let $$a_n=\sum_{j=1}^nb_j$$
You can prove that for all integer $n>0,\;\;a_n$ is bounded:
$$0\leq a_n\leq 1$$
It does not converge since 
$$a_n=1\qquad\text{if }\;\;n=T_{2p-1}\;\text{ for any integer }p>0\\a_n=0\qquad\text{if }\;\;n=T_{2p}\;\text{ for any integer }p>0$$

Answer (score 1):

If you mean for $(a_n)$ to be a sequence, then consider the sequence

$$1,-1/2,-1/2, 1/3,1/3,1/3,-1/4,-1/4,-1/4,-1/4,\dots$$