# Problem on bounded divergent sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am facing difficulties with the following problem

> Find a bounded divergent real sequence $\{x_n\}$ such that $x_{n+1}-x_n \rightarrow 0.$

This problem has solution in [Divergent bounded sequence such that limit of the difference between two consecutive elements is zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1733779/809050)

I have considered $x_n=\sin(\sum_1^n \frac{1}{k})$ but I am unable to prove that it is divergent.

Please help if my example is correct.

Comment: The example is correct, though it is probably easier to consider $x_n:=\sin(\log n)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $H_n:=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k$. Let $x>0$. For $n\in\Bbb N$, let $\varphi(n)\in\Bbb N$ be the unique integer such that $$H_{\varphi(n)+1}>x+2n\pi\ge H_{\varphi(n)}.$$
Check that:

1. $\varphi(n)\to\infty$;
2. $H_{\varphi(n)}=2n\pi+x+O(\frac1{\varphi(n)})$;
3. $\sin(H_{\varphi(n)})=\sin\left(x+O(\frac1{\varphi(n)})\right).$

Answer (score 0):

Your example is correct. Let $z_n:=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k$ and we have that
$$x_{n+1}-x_n=\sin(z_{n+1})-\sin(z_n)=2\cos\left(\frac{z_{n+1}+z_{n}}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{1}{2(n+1)}\right)$$
since $2\cos\left(\frac{z_{n+1}+z_{n}}{2}\right)$ is bounded, and $\sin\left(\frac{1}{2(n+1)}\right)\to 0$ when $n\to\infty$. On the other hand it is clear that $(\sin(z_n))$ is divergent.

$\color{red}{\text{[Here I had not remembered that the succession needed to be limited.]}}$ But I think taking $x_n:=\log(n)$ or $x_n:=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}$ would make everything easier.

Comment: $x_n:=\log(n)$ or $x_n:=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k$ would not work as they do not form bounded sequences.

Comment: @nejimban If you are right, I have already modified it.